# A Special Case of Difference-in-Differences

Tags: econometrics, reference-request, applied-econometrics

I remember reading a paper where the Difference-in-Differences was a bit special, but I had forgotten the details. My recollection was

- Two time periods, specifically one time period before treatment and one time period after treatment.
- The "treatment" was such that ***all*** firms had to comply with a certain share of a variable X.
- The ***treatment group*** consisted of firms with very low (or zero) share of X before the treatment, and
- The ***control group*** consisted of firms with a share already close to the required share of X before the treatment.

The idea was that the treatment group received most of the shock, while the control group was little affected.

Do you know a paper that uses such a framework?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Ch 5 of Mastering Metrics (Angrist and Pischke) or their earlier "Mostly harmless econometrics".

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question, which is looking for the title of a paper.

Comment: My reading is that the OP is asking for examples that need not appear in papers as opposed to books. The book of course contains references to papers.

Comment: @LutzHendricks Thanks. I know those books that tend to present the classic case (where only the treatment group is treated and not all the subjects). I'm really looking for papers here.

Comment: The chapter in Mostly Harmless Econometrics cites a few papers:
Card, David, and Alan Krueger (1994): “Minimum Wages and Employment: A Case Study of the Fast Food Industry in New Jersey and Pennsylvania.” The American Economic Review 84, 772-84. 
—— (2000): “Minimum Wages and Employment: A Case Study of the Fast-Food Industry in New Jersey and Pennsylvania: Reply.” The American Economic Review 90, 1397-420.
There also the papers by Pischke, Autor 2003, Card 1992.
Perhaps I misunderstand what you are looking for, but these seem to fit the bill.

Comment: @LutzHendricks I am aware of this paper. See this [thread](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/in-difference-in-difference-approach-would-it-be-possible-to-add-a-dummy-variab/36009#36009). In Card-Krueger only New Jersey raised the state minimum, not eastern Pennsylvania. Please read my "treatment" and the difference between my treatment and control groups.